# Linking to c++ libraries in babel code block

Tags: org-babel, c++

The title says it all, and I've included the relevant sections of my file below.  I'm  trying to create a src block that uses some functionality of the boost libraries, the first src block sets up the compiler, including the libraries to link to.  The second src block is just a test function, but it quits with a linker error.

```
#+begin_src elisp :exports results
   (setq org-babel-C++-compiler
       (concat "g++ -std=c++0x"
               " -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem"
               " -I"
               (expand-file-name ".")
       )
   )
#+end_src


#+begin_src C++ :exports both :includes (list "\"boost/filesystem.hpp\"" "<stdio.h>")
 printf("testing\n");
#+end_src
```

The error:

> /tmp/ccvz9bRM.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>   C-src-2374gem.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
>   C-src-2374gem.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
>   C-src-2374gem.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   /bin/bash: /tmp/babel-2374l5F/C-bin-2374tos: No such file or directory

Comment: Perhaps the directory containing the boost library is not in the path searched by `ld`.  Try adding `-L/path/to/boost` before `-lboost_system`

Comment: I tried adding the path and the error still occurred.  Judging by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter, it's the order it's being linked in that's causing the problem.

Comment: Hmm yes.  I see what the problem is now.   You need the `-lboost_system` argument to go after the name of the source file in the compilation command.  Looking at the source for `org-babel-C-execute`, there seems to be no provision for doing that.  There is a `:flags` argument, but that gets put before the source file name.  If my understanding is right you will have to hack that function by hand, or send a feature request to the orgmode mailing list.

Comment: It's an easy enough fix, it's only two lines that need to be switched.  I sent a bug report, and I've changed it in my own file.  @deprecated, thanks for looking at it.  Should this question be closed then?

Comment: Great! I suggest that you write up a summary of your fix as an answer below, which you can then accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it's not necessary to use the elisp code included.  The flags property lets compiler flags be passed,

:flags "-lboost_system -std=c++0x"

Unfortunately, due to the order the flags are passed in it's necessary to do some lisp hacking in order to allow linking.

1. Open the file with the definition of org-babel-C-execute:  <kbd>C-h f</kbd>   org-babel-C-execute, then click on the source file to open it.
2. Switch the last two arguments to format. It should be 
   `(format "%s -o %s %s %s"
            (cond
             ((equal org-babel-c-variant 'c) org-babel-C-compiler)
             ((equal org-babel-c-variant 'cpp) org-babel-C++-compiler))
            (org-babel-process-file-name tmp-bin-file)
            (org-babel-process-file-name tmp-src-file)
            (mapconcat 'identity
               (if (listp flags) flags (list flags)) " ")
            ) ""))))`
3. Load the new function with  <kbd>M-x</kbd>  compile-defun
4. If you had the file byte compiled, recompile the file with byte-compile-file.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:libs` to specify libraries.

```
((or `c `cpp)
 (org-babel-eval
  (format "%s -o %s %s %s %s"
    (pcase org-babel-c-variant
      (`c org-babel-C-compiler)
      (`cpp org-babel-C++-compiler))
    tmp-bin-file
    flags
    (org-babel-process-file-name tmp-src-file)
    libs)
   ""))
```

As we can see, org-babel-C-execute will inserts `:flags` in front of the source file and `:libs` behind it.